# Multiple Get in django templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-pagination

Hi I have multiple pagination in a single page.
Lets say, I am displaying two lists. list1 and list2. in the views I have paginated them using django paginator and I GET two variables list1_page and list2_page.

now my template looks like this

```
{{ list1_page_obj.object_list }}
{% if list1_page_obj.has_next %}
<a href='?list1_page={{ list1_page_obj.next_page_number }}'>NEXT</a>
{% endif %}

{{ list2_page_obj.object_list }}
{% if list2_page_obj.has_next %}
<a href='?list2_page={{ list1_page_obj.next_page_number }}'>NEXT</a>
{% endif %}
```

now the thing is if I am on the second page of list1 and I click on NEXT page of list2 I get the next page of list 2 but the first page of list1 is displayed.

basically if I am on http://foo.com/?list1_page=xx and I click on NEXT on list2 I get
http://foo.com/?list2_page=yy
I want it to redirect to http://foo.com/?list1_page=xx&list2_page=yy

Answer (score 1):

I guess, your pagination function have the problem... I do not know your pagination function variable names but probably you are making the mistake in;

```
next_page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
```

where **'page'** is the variable that keeps your page info, so in your code there must be two paginator block with these two lines included separately...

```
lsit1_page = int(request.GET.get('list1_page', 1))
```

and

```
lsit2_page = int(request.GET.get('list2_page', 1))
```